# fullcalender.formatdate not working

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to integrate fullcalender to php mysql.I have used the following code.I want to format the date such it will come in format yyyy/mm/dd but when i use format statements the code isn't working properly.If i remove format date it seems working but inserting 0000/0000/000 00:00 in the database.

my code:

```
 // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
 eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
   if (event.allDay === 'true') {
     event.allDay = true;
   } 
   else {
     event.allDay = false;
   }
 },
 selectable: true,
 selectHelper: true,
 select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   var title = prompt('Sample Textbox:');
   if (title) {
     start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
     end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
     $.ajax({
       url: 'http://localhost/fullcalendar/demos/add_events.php',
       data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end  ,
       type: "POST",
       success: function(json) {
         alert('Added Successfully');
         alert(json);
       }
    });   
    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
      {
        title: title,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        allDay: allDay
      },
      true // make the event "stick"
    );
  }
  calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

Can anybody tell me what is the issue?
If i remove format date it's working else it's not working. But i must format the data to get it properly inserted in the database. I just want date only no need of hours.

Comment: Is this mysql question?

Comment: No i need date format should be in datetime format field in mysql.

Answer (score 13):

First if you are looking for date only not hours, you should probably use:

```
start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy/MM/dd");
end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Instead of this:

```
start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

If you remove date format it seems working because it's inserting dates like a timestamp (it looks like timestamp).
Try changing your database structure type to VARCHAR and you will see something like this:

```
1405468800000
```

---

When you are using dateFormat function, you should look in your web browser console logs. You'll probably see:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It's because `$.fullCalendar.formatDate` method no more exist on fullCalendar V2 ([changeLog](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/)).
You may use `Moment.js` with `.format()` method ([doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)).

Don't forget to import `moment.js` and edit your `start` and `end` variables to:

```
start=moment(start).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
end=moment(end).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```

It should fix your issues.

Answer (score 5):

this code below should do the trick. (assuming you have the moment.min.js lib)

```
        start=moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ'); 
        end=moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
```

Answer (score 3):

As [Tifa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24780414/86072) suggests : if you don't need the time part, don't encode it :

```
start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

---

Another problem lies in the parameter string you pass to your ajax request :

```
data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end  ,
```

This string is not url encoded.

The easiest way to correct this is to pass an object, and let jQuery handle the encoding :

```
data: {'title': title, 'start': start, 'end': end } ,
```

Answer (score 0):

The "DD**T**HH:mm" addition will fail on some versions - bets to leave it out and use a pure date format. Add the 'Z' to compensate for the time zone if you wish.

```
select: function(start, end){

           var converted_start = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD:HH:mm:ssZ');// the "Z" will adjust for time zone
           var converted_end = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD:HH:mm:ssZ');

        },
```