# how to solve $.fullCalendar.formatDate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar api for my application ,I am trying to disable the past dates in the fullcalendar ,but I am getting `$.fullCalendar.formatDate` is not a function error.I am posting my code

```
select : function(start, end, allDay) {
        $('#clickedDateHolder').val(start.format());
        // show modal dialog
        var check = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'yyyy-MM-dd');
        var today = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd');

        if(check < today)
        {
            bootbox.alert("Past Dates")
        }else{
            input.push(date.format());
            $('#selectedDate').val(input);
            $('#event-modal').modal('show');
```

So in this code I am trying to see which date  is past date in fullcalendar and trying to give a message of that  but each time I am getting this error.Somebody please help

Comment: Have you tried `$.fullCalendar().formatDate()`? It's probably a function.

Comment: post the console error and html code also

Comment: TypeError: $.fullCalendar.formatDate is not a function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729721/fullcalender-formatdate-not-working

Answer (score 9):

FullCalendar's formatDate() was only for versions below 2.0. See here: http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/

> $.fullCalendar.formatDate → use a moment's .format() method instead

So instead of

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

you have to use

```
moment(start, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

whereas `'DD.MM.YYYY'` is the recent format of `start` and `format('YYYY-MM-DD')` specifies the target format. Pay attention, you need to use capitalized letters.

Answer (score 0):

your scripts might be conflicting with some other scripts, try adding all your code inside this instead of `$(document).ready()`

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // your code
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: if the confliction occurs its show the conflict message instead  of not a function error

Comment: @AkhileshSingh such error has occurred to me before and the solution was this so i said 'might be'